# How to perform redirect after login with the Modal Forms module?

Tags: javascript, redirection

I have some pages in my website with links using the [Modal forms (with ctools)](https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_forms) module to login. I want to redirect users after logging in using these modals to the same page that have the link to this modal form

Any idea how do this?

Comment: Answers from [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/19110/16495) does not work for you? How do they fail?

Answer (score 0):

The page callback of the login URL provided by the [Modal Forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_forms) module is `modal_forms_login`.

```
/*
 * A modal user login callback.
 */
function modal_forms_login($js = NULL) {
  // Fall back if $js is not set.
  if (!$js) {
    return drupal_get_form('user_login');
  }

  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_include('ajax');
  $form_state = array(
    // 'title' => t('Log in'),
    'ajax' => TRUE,
  );

  $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('user_login', $form_state);
  if (!empty($form_state['executed'])) {
    // We'll just overwrite the form output if it was successful.
    $output = array();
    ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');
    $output[] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss(t('Login success'));
    if (isset($_GET['destination'])) {
      $output[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect($_GET['destination']);
    }
    elseif(module_exists('login_destination')) {
      $destination = login_destination_get_destination('login');
      $output[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect($destination['path']);
    }
    else {
      $output[] = ctools_ajax_command_reload();
    }
  }
  print ajax_render($output);
}
```

At a quick glance, you can tell that you can either set your destination in the query string of your login link, like so:

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');
$login_link = l('Login', 'modal_forms/nojs/login', array(
  'query' => array('destination' => 'redirect-here'),
  'html' => TRUE,
  'attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('ctools-use-modal'),
  )
));
```

Or, install and configure the [Login Destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination) module

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is my solution:

1) create a module mymodule

2) override menu item using `hook_menu`

```
function mymodule_menu(){
    $items['modal_forms/%ctools_js/login'] = array(
        'title' => 'Log in',
        'page callback' => 'mymodule_modal_forms_login', // your custom callback function
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'file' => 'mymodule.module', // file with the mymodule_modal_forms_login function 
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
}
```

3) copy and paste from model_forms.page.inc on your mymodule.module file and change the name y the body of the function

```
function vdf_modal_forms_login($js = NULL) {
global $user;

// Fall back if $js is not set.
if (!$js) {
    return drupal_get_form('user_login');
}

ctools_include('modal');
ctools_include('ajax');
$form_state = array(
    // 'title' => t('Log in'),
    'ajax' => TRUE,
);

$output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('user_login', $form_state);
if (!empty($form_state['executed'])) {
    // We'll just overwrite the form output if it was successful.
    $output = array();
    ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');
    $output[] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss(t('Login success'));

    if (in_array("custom_role_1", $user->roles)) {
        $output[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect("custom_page_1");
    } elseif (in_array("custom_role_2", $user->roles)){
        $output[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect("custom_page_2");
    }else {
        $output[] = ctools_ajax_command_redirect("custom_page_3");
    }
}
print ajax_render($output);
}
```